# RabbitHealthIndicator - Health check failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-integration-amqp

Have a similar situation as we have here [Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMQ health check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683347/spring-cloud-stream-and-rabbitmq-health-check)

**Error message**

```
2018-12-04 05:17:31.768  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-12-04 05:17:31.775  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.a.health.RabbitHealthIndicator     : Health check failed

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:586) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1436) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1417) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1393) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.RabbitHealthIndicator.getVersion(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:49) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.RabbitHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:43) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:86) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:36) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AbstractEndpointMvcAdapter.invoke(AbstractEndpointMvcAdapter.java:56) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke(EndpointMvcAdapter.java:42) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor559.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64) [spring-security-core-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54) [spring-security-core-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.webbfontaine.grails.plugins.security.keycloak.filter.KeycloakTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(KeycloakTokenValidationFilter.java:66) [wf-security-keycloak-3.3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:75) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:82) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58) [spring-security-core-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77) [grails-web-mvc-3.3.8.jar:3.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67) [grails-web-mvc-3.3.8.jar:3.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.53]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:367) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 115 common frames omitted
```

**Environment:**

- Java 8
- Grails 3.3.8
- spring-rabbit-1.7.9.RELEASE
- spring-boot-actuator-1.5.15.RELEASE
- keycloak server 4.6.0.Final

Tried to disable Rabbit auto configuration in my **application.yaml** file

`spring:
    autoconfigure:
        exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
management:
  context-path: '/manage'`

**Request :** **myapp/manage/health**

**Response :**

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 58963079168,
    "free": 47464902656,
    "threshold": 10485760
  },
  "rabbit": {
    "status": "DOWN",
    "error": "org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"
  }
}
```

Any Idea how can disable rabbit here ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This configuration is solution for such a case for for application.yml

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
```

The issue in external application.yaml file, when added this configuration in my local application.yml inside the project everything works fine.

And for application.properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: For the people who are using application.properties please include below line in your file -
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 15):

You can disable the rabbitmq in your application.properties file:

management.health.rabbit.enabled: false

Comment: It doesn't work if RabbitTemplate bean is registered (looks like a bug). The logs shows "o.s.b.a.condition.OnClassCondition       : Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitHealthContributorAutoConfiguration matched due to @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate'" which gives indication that "...rabbit.enabled: false" was ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the above answers are correct, but there is a different error here. If your spring application cannot connect to the rabbitmq server while starting up, it gives such an error. If you do the rabbitmq configuration correctly, there is no need to turn off the health check.

Comment: I have that error too and I'm not even using RabbitMQ. I'm connecting to an Oracle AQ queue. So I haven't found any other way except for excluding that auto configuration to get rid of that annoying warning.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet Hi Andreas, I think you proceed this way because there was a connection error there as well. If it wasn't for the connection issue, you wouldn't need to disable it. Of course that's my opinion. Have a nice day!

Comment: As this error happens everytime, yet a connection is established and the queue is immediately processed after the initialization I don't think it's a connection error.