# RabbitHealthIndicator - Rabbit health check failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I tried all of top solutions found in SO and I am still not able to make actuator/health endpoints work.

[rabbithealthindicator-health-check-failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606426/rabbithealthindicator-health-check-failed)

[how-to-disable-rabbit-health-check-via-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203863/how-to-disable-rabbit-health-check-via-configuration)

I still get following error.

> **303 [http-nio-31032-exec-2] [INFO] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory] - Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
> 09:27 18:23:03.404 [http-nio-31032-exec-2] [WARN] [org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator] - Rabbit health check failed
> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> at** org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2089) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2062) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2042) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> **Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]

**I tried following configuration and none of it worked**

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
```

---

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
    health:
       show-details: always
 endpoint:
   health:
     probes:
       enabled: true
health:
  rabbit:
    enabled: false
  livenessState:
    enabled: true
  readinessState:
    enabled: true
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
```

---

```
@Bean
public HealthIndicator rabbitHealthIndicator() {
    return () -> Health.up().withDetail("version", "mock").build();
}
```

---

**I added application.properties file too with the following**

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true
management.health.rabbit.enabled=false
```

Comment: `Connection Refused` simply means that there is nothing listening for connections on `localhost:5672`.